# эмуляция position absolute в верстке писем

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

необходимо вырвать изображение из общего потока документа, но position absolute игнорируется почтовиками.
как можно это провернуть?

p.s. нашел на английском вот это решение

So first of all you need to set a container to position against.

Then place an element inside that, set display as inline-block and position it with margin-top and margin-left.

N.B. Unfortunately negative values in the margin won't work in Gmail, Outlook.com or 365.

The element is now behaving similar to position:relative but we want position:absolute so as not to affect the flow of any neighbouring elements.  To achieve this wrap the inner element in a div with max-height:0;max-width:0 this now mean that div takes up no space on the page, but the overflow can still be seen.

You can now place multiple elements in that container and position them absolute. In this example I've added outlines and semi transparent background colours to clear display the outcome.

я пробую его реализовать разными способами, но у меня не получается, возможно я что то не понимаю на уровне английского языка, использование переводчика тоже не помогает. не могли бы вы помочь с переводом
главной информации по теме из этой статьи?

Comment: конкретно я не пойму часть про - 
So first of all you need to set a container to position against.

Comment: В данном решении предлагается использовать отрицательные отступы. Они работают примерно как position:relative;. Но также в этом же решении и сказано, что этот метод не сработает в популярных почтовых клиентах.

Comment: Приведите пример, что вы хотите сделать - всегда есть способы решить проблему верстки, пойдя на какие-то уступки.